# Select row on table

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

I have a table below my search input like below:

[image]

how to select the appropriate item from the list below using the arrows on the keyboard? additionally, it would be good if the currently selected element had a different color

here is my code:

```
<div class="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch" style="width: 450px;">
          <span
            class="z-10 h-full leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 absolute bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3"
          >
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </span>
          <input
            v-model.trim="searchBy"
            @keyup.enter="getAllDatas"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Find more data..."
            class="px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative bg-white bg-white rounded text-sm shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full pl-10"
          />
          <br />
          <table class="v-full" style="border: 1px solid #333;width: 450px;border-radius:5%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="r in data.items" :key="r.id">
                <td style="border: 1px solid #333;background-color: #ffffff;" v-on:click="getData(r.id)">{{ r.name }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

I have no idea how to do this :(

thanks for any help

Comment: You've departed a fair bit from both coding and UI convention by using a table there. Normally it's a list, which has built-in support for such navigation and selection. Is there some reason you need a table?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: @isherwood, Hi, no is there no reason but i'm sooo weak in styles and I have not found any other solution, can you show how to do this properly?

Comment: google html select option

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I use datalist but i don't know why my keypress.enter not work on my element and not launch my function to preload page, can you showa an simply example of using this in vuejs?

Comment: A good example here, though I'm not recommending you use jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Why build this yourself when there are so many plugins you can use?